# YAML overwitten by Ambari while starting Storm UI

Tags: apache-storm, hortonworks-data-platform

I needed to change the number of ***supervisor.slots.port=[6700, 6701, 6702, 6703, 6704] to 5 ports*** and also the number of workers available to a single topology by ***topology.workers=5***.

Also these changes I have made as per the suggestion in storm documentation to change the config file called *"**storm.yaml**"*.Now the trouble I am facing is when I try to restart the Storm UI Service using the command "***./storm ui***", it is unable to completely execute it and gets stuck. On the other hand, if I try to do the same under Ambari Services tab, I am able to start Storm UI but then it ***overwrites my "storm.yaml"*** and it then **deaults to supervisor.slots.port=[6700, 6701] and topology.workers=1**
My Storm Version is: 0.9.1.2.1.1.0-385

I am not sure how to fix that now and I am trying to find if someone has solved this issue.

Comment: Storm ui not being able to start is the problem? Do you have a stack of why it can't start?

Comment: @zenbeni It gives no stack and the reason is that, it just gets stuck in between the process. So i could not get any error stack to determine what I can do next.

Comment: Did you try to run the explicit java command that the storm script builds with all logs on debug? It can't be that silent.

Comment: Why don't you use ambari to set supervisor.slots.ports? Ambari will set the configuration (as you've seen) for you. Go to Ambari -> Storm -> Configs, change the config, save and restart components.

Comment: @KitMenke hey thanks to you, i was able to solve the configuration of supervisor.slots.ports from ambari itself using Ambari->Storm->Config.
Actually I hadn't noticed that this config tab has setting for properties same as "storm.yaml" and avoided changes there to not mess anything unknowingly.
So can you please post your comment as an answer and i will accept it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Ambari installed and can see the Storm service listed, then you can just manage storm there and Ambari will set the configuration (as you've seen) for you.

Go to Ambari -> Storm -> Configs, change the config (look for supervisor.slots.ports), save and restart components.